# Auto number input to google spreadsheet using array

Tags: google-apps-script, spreadsheet

I have started studying GAS  recently. 
I wrote Auto number script using  Low number.
There is spreadsheet has some datas, I want put A Column including batch ID number at one time.

```
function autoID() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
for(i=1; i<= lastrow-1; i++)
{
var num = sheet.getRange(i,1);
num.setValue(i);
}  
 Browser.msgBox("This is end!");
}
```

This in **no good example**,it takes too much time.

I wonder  I should use Array() ..
may be ↓　this is hint..

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/best_practices

But this Best Practices　doesn't work, I tried this...

```
 function autoID() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
 var num = new Array();
 idrange = sheet.getRamge("A2:A"+(lastrow-1));
 idrange = idrange.getValues();
 for(i=1; i<= lastrow-1; i++)
 {
 var num = sheet.getRange(i,1);
  num[(i)]=i;
 }  
 Browser.messageBox(num[1]); // this is 1;
 idrange.setValues(num); // this is error
 }
```

How is change type?

Please help me..

I think this must be so easy.

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I understood exactly what you want to do but here is how it works without code errors :

```
function autoID() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastrow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var num = new Array();
  var idrange = sheet.getRange("A2:A"+(lastrow));
  var idrangeVal = idrange.getValues() 
  for(var i in idrangeVal){
    num.push([i]);
  }  
  idrange.setValues(num); 
}
```

---

### edit following your comment :

Here is a version the (I hope) does what you expected...

```
function autoID() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var valuesInrangeA = sheet.getRange('A2:A').getValues();
  var maxA = 0
  for(var n=0 ;n<valuesInrangeA.length ; n++){
    if(valuesInrangeA[n][0]!=''){maxA=n+2};
  };
  var num = new Array();
  for(var i=1 ; i<maxA ; i++){
    num.push([i]);
  }  
  sheet.getRange("B2:B"+maxA).setValues(num);
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!　I get Idea！I am so happy!

Comment: Thank you very much.First one enough.Now,I understand this.  But,your next answer also told me many Idea.Thank you(*^-^*)